# How to share the port 8080 between docker host and docker container with out port conflict?

Tags: docker, networking, containers, port

I am new to docker and not able to implement a requirement. I have to run the apache Tomcat on docker host and apache on container.
But here is the catch or confusing part, apache Tomcat is already running on docker host( which default using port 8080) which launches the docker container. Now, I am not able to launch the apache configclient.html from container. The docker network I used is *host network*, `-net=host` , while running the container.

The point here is docker host , on which container is running, is also using the port 8080 for running apache tomcat. So, now docker host and container both using same port 8080.

How can I resolve the port conflict between docker host and docker container where both are using port 8080!?
Any help/suggestion to make way here to run the apache on container and apache tomcat on host with out changing the port address?! . Please note, I am using private network here. `(ip ->192.168.xx.xx)`.
I have found many links which explains the sharing port 80 among the containers. But my requirement is different here!!. Please forgive me for any silly query or bad presentation while framing this question.

Comment: You shouldn't need host networking, particularly for HTTP-type services.  Can you remove the `--net host` option, but add a `-p 12345:8080` to map a different host port to the Apache server's HTTP port?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks David. My host is missing docker-proxy required for port mapping may be. You are right, right now I better not to use the -net=host and try with simple port mapping option -p may be.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reverse www proxy on the host that sends a subpath to the container.

If this is not the answer, than you have an ambiguity in your requirement as it must be possible for the host OS to resolve which calls go to the host and which to the container.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please be more descriptive about what you mean by reverse www proxy. Any links regarding the information will be very helpful. I am very new to networking and even to docker containerization.